# How to query management.azure.com with a GET request?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-application-insights

I used to use Public API format in order to authenticate with AppId and ApiKey.

Quite recently I had to authenticate with Azure Active Directory in order to query Application Insights.

As I understood reading [this](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization) when I use Azure Active Directory I have to use `management.azure.com`. From what I've learned from [this](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Overview/URL-formats) I need to compose a link:

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/microsoft.insights/components/{componentName}/query/query?api-version={apiVersion}&query={newQuery}`

If I understand correctly the weird `/query/query` part is how I should interpret `/{area}/[path]`.

My query looks something like this:

```
requests
| where name =~ '{itemName}'
| where timestamp > datetime('{referenceDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")}')
| project timestamp, id, name, success, customDimensions
| order by timestamp desc
| take 5
```

I do remove the line breaks :-)

I call the API this way:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

    var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

But I get Bad Request.

I need to GET query Application Insights with AAD authentication (which I already solved, as without the line with Auth or with bad value I get Unauthorized). When registering the application in Azure Active Directory I was not given any options to add permissions than Data.Read - when using Post (different code than presented) I did get "Method Not Allowed".

Please advise.

**Edit**

I tried running the same query in Postman.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The request had some invalid properties",
    "code": "BadArgumentError",
    "innererror": {
        "code": "SemanticError",
        "message": "A semantic error occurred.",
        "innererror": {
            "code": "SEM0100",
            "message": "'' operator: Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named 'requests'"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Even when I shortened the `query` parameter to `requests`. So I guess I don't know how to pass a query in a GET API call.

Comment: To run an Analytics query try using the API endpoint described here: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the API format should be like as below, not the one in your question, it can be found in the powershell script in this [link](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourcegroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appinsight-name>/api/query?api-version=2014-12-01-preview&query=requests|where timestamp > ago(24h)|count
```

Actually, if you want to call this API with Azure AD Authentication, the best way I can find is to use [`Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#using-the-library) library, no need to create the AD App, just get the access token with the code as below, then use the token to call the API.

**Note**: When you run the code, make sure your user account which log in Visual Studio is an [RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)(e.g. `Owner`/`Contributor`) in your subscription or App insight. If not, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal#grant-access) to grant access.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/").Result;
        Console.WriteLine(accessToken);
    }
```

I test the token in postman, it works fine, you can also use it in code.

[image]

Comment: Going with your description step by step I realised that `/query/query` should be `/api/query` and API-Version should be `2014-12-01-preview`. That actually solved my problem. Thank you, Joy :-)